# How to create Azure pipeline CICD for docker container to linux on premises server?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a containerized app's image that builds on master push and ends up in Azure container registry. I need to setup the next step where this image ends up on my Linux on prem server.

I have established the connection with the server using a deployment group agent, which claims it is healthy.

I have created a pipeline which takes the built image artifact as input but I am completely failing to grasp and create the step in which the artifact is being pulled on / pushed to the server (and ideally run too).

I am looking at the tasks in the pipelines > task section in Azure DevOps but I cannot find a place to add some specific steps neither I am very sure what steps to add.

I would very much appreciate any tip on how to deploy a container from acr to on premises Linux server using Azure DevOps pipelines. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link which shows how to create Azure Pipeline CI/CD for docker container ,make sure all these steps are followed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops

Comment: you can run commands on a remote machine using SSH tasks in Azure DevOps. Before that you need to connect a service connection to an on-prem VM. Then use SSH task to connect to on-prem VM and run the docker commands or scripts you needed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/ssh?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml